# Apache Stop Working - AH00428 -- Restarting

Tags: php, windows, apache

I need help.
I can not solve this problem.

My configs:

- Intel Core I5 - 3,2 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- Windows 7 Enterprise x64 SP1

Versions:

- httpd-2.4.23-win32-VC11
- php-5.6.24-Win32-VC11-x86
- instantclient-basic-win32-11.2.0.1.0
- php_oci8-2.0.8-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip

What happens is that, I start the service without any error.

But when I open a page that contains PHP, the Apache resets (*AH00428: Parent: child process 4608 exited with status 3958377386 -- Restarting.*).

Windows returns me the error message: "Apache HTTPD Server stopped working."

Follow the apache error.log:

```
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:22.320400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:22.320400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:22.320400 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24' 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:22.336400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4608 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:22.914400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4608:tid 632] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:50.895400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00428: Parent: child process 4608 exited with status 3958377386 -- Restarting. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:51.035400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:51.035400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:51.035400 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24' 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:51.051400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5172 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:51.661400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5172:tid 632] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:52.388400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00428: Parent: child process 5172 exited with status 3958377386 -- Restarting. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:52.491400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:52.491400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul  7 2016 11:13:22 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:52.491400 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24' 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:52.506400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1120 
[Tue Aug 16 09:35:53.062400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1120:tid 628] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads. 
Apache server interrupted... 
[Tue Aug 16 09:36:22.150400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:36:24.151400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1120:tid 628] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited. 
[Tue Aug 16 09:36:24.214400 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4864:tid 616] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1120 exited successfully.
```

access.log is empty.

I can not fix this. 
Any tips? 
Thanks.

---

**Edit**

I looked at windows event log and found this:

```
Application Error 
EventRecordID 72126 
Channel Application
EventData:
httpd.exe 
2.4.23.0 
577e1b96 
KERNELBASE.dll 
6.1.7601.18229 
51fb1116 
ebf00baa 
0000c41f 
e2c 
01d1f7de4709ca89 
C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe 
C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll 
9238afff-63d1-11e6-bca1-641c67645206
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

I disable all PHP extensions and looked at the windows event log.

Was giving error as follows:

```
Application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.23.0 
Module: php5apache2_4.dll, versão: 0.0.0.0 
Exception Code: 0xc0000005 
Application path failed: C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe 
Fault module path: C:\PHP\php5apache2_4.dll 
Report Identification: cae5d4a7-6486-11e6-bca1-641c67645206
```

I deleted the PHP folder, wiped the register, downloaded again, and enabled the extensions needed. 
And now is functioning normally.